# Alphanumeric voice recognition from phone

Tags: android, forms, voice-recognition, google-voice

Is there a way to pass alphanumeric from Google voice recognition on an Android device to an open text field?

Example: "123" instead of "one two three"

Comment: the phone is doing what its told to use. if the user says one hundred and twenty three, the phone should then output 123. my pixel does anyway

Comment: You are quite right. The Google voice keyboard seems to handle this fine. Some of my users were complaining about this problem, but it must be specific to a virtual keyboard. Thanks :)

Comment: One problem that Google voice typing still has though, is sporadic recognition of "to", "too", and "2". When testing with multiple people, we get different results each time. Maybe there is some keyword like "number" then "2"?

Comment: Are you only looking at the first result from the recognition, or the entire array? My experience is, it offers both in the suggestions.

Comment: my voice picks up the right too to or 2. it depends on the context of the sentence.

Comment: I am trying to use it to populate serial numbers on a form. For example:

"E0072" will sometimes read correctly, and other times it will read "E007 too". Wish there was a setting or keyword to say before numbers/letters.

(I'm using Google voice typing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2)

Comment: Conclusion is that it is sporadic, but will likely improve with Google voice typing updates.